# I need to manipulate the input area

Tags: javascript, jquery, paste, data-manipulation, dom-manipulation

I need to manipulate the input for good reasons.
I have an websites where customers buy some social media services and to order they need to paste their links.
Some peoples write/paste wrong urls and I need to somehow to auto correct them.

**Here is the html part**

```
<input name="link" id="link" value="" data-validation="required" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text">
```

So, if someone paste/write let's say

- http://www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/
- www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/
- instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/

i need somehow to be changed in to

- https://www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1

**Second problem are with "?" in the url**

So, if someone paste/write let's say

- https://www.facebook.com/spiderdebigode/posts/1409535075841821?notif_id=1516499075370350&notif_t=feedback_reaction_generic
- https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10214957270023041&set=a.3025169626062.151861.1167395781&type=3&theater

to have only :

- https://www.facebook.com/spiderdebigode/posts/1409535075841821
- https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10214957270023041

Comment: Where are you you facing the problem? Have you tried anything yet to manipulate the Data?

Comment: You're asking for the whole solution.  Please, share a minimal version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. it removes the protocol and get params, then concatenates your the https protocol and the domain.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#link')

const urls = [
  'http://www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/',
  'www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/',
  'instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/',
  '//www.instagram.com/p/BVh_CbaA9Y1/?get=param',
  'https://www.facebook.com/spiderdebigode/posts/1409535075841821?notif_id=15',
  'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10214957270023041',
]

const normalizeUrl = url => 
  'https://www.' +
    url
      .slice(0, url.indexOf('?')) // cut out the get params
      .replace(/(https?\:)*(\/\/)*(www\.)*/, '') // remove the protocol

// on changing the input, normalize the input value
input.addEventListener('change', e => {
  input.value = normalizeUrl(input.value)
}, false)

// test each format of url
urls.forEach(url => {
  console.log(normalizeUrl(url))
})
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } input { width: 100%; padding: .5em; }
```

```html
<input class="form-control" 
  name="link" 
  id="link" 
  value="" 
  data-validation="required" 
  placeholder="Enter you url here, on change it will be normalized" 
  type="text">
```

Comment: no it's not necessary to use the included script, it is just for presentation on stackoverflow. You will need to get the value from the input field, run the `normalizeUrl` function on the value and replace it.

Comment: added your code before to close the body tag, between <script>js code</script> but not working.I put this script only on the order page where customers type/paste links

Comment: What I provided was the generic code to normalise the input. You only needed to add the event. I have added it.